# Why does Rust enforce objects can only be mutably borrowed once?

Tags: pointers, types, rust, type-systems

Isn't there already `Send`/`Sync`? The official document only mentions it has something to do with data races.

Comment: Have you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.15.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html ? The first (interesting) example is [Iterator Invalidation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.15.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html#iterator-invalidation) which has *nothing* to do with data races. Data race freedom is actually mostly a fallout of the **Aliasing XOR Mutability** principle which underlies borrow checking; the cherry on top of the cake so to speak.

Comment: @MatthieuM. tsk, tsk, linking to that old, out of date documentation. Didn't you know that Rust 1.16.0 came out literally hours ago?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Alas, a few hours too late! Fortunately, it made it up having `cargo check`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of **memory safety**.

Consider this example (disregard the fact that this would result in an infinite loop if it compiled):

```
let mut list = vec![1, 2, 3];
for item in &list {
    list.push(*item + 1);
    println!("item = {}", item);
}
```

`item` is a reference to the memory held by `list`; it is of type `&i32`. You may read the value of that element by dereferencing it (`*item`).

What would happen to the reference in `item` if the `push` call were to reallocate the vector's memory to a different address?

The reference would then contain the *old* address. Any attempt to access it would involve reading some undefined chunk of memory. This violates a core Rust safety principle.

> Isn't there already `Send`/`Sync`

`Send` and `Sync` are concerned with multiple threads. As you can see from the example above, you don't need threads to potentially produce invalid references.

Comment: Can you reallocate without having ownership?

Comment: @盛安安 yes. To call `push`, you only need `&mut Vec<T>`.